# HTML tags getting converted to text

Tags: html

I have a situation where when I pass in < b r > in a piece of content that is meant to work as a html output, it converts the br tag and instead outputs it as a plain text. Is there a way to handle this where I can pass in converted br tag and still make it work as a br tag? I am not looking for solutions which involves any usage of JS methods or any methods.

I have no control on either sides, part where I add the content nor the place which reads it other than see the display outcome.

For example I am passing in following content (< b r/> same issue. Leaving spaces in this tag so that you can see it and not end up with an actual breakpoint):

```
start <br> end
```

Expected outcome:

> start 
>  end

Actual outcome

```
start <br> end
```

From what I checked, the br tag got converted to following:

```
start &lt;br&gt; end
```

Is there a way I can still use & l t ; b r & g t; and make it work as a br tag?

Been messing around using the W3Schools Editor but nothing works. Please advice.

W3School screenshot as requested:

[image: Screenshot]

[W3School Editor](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default)

Comment: Where are you entering this into? Some sort of forum? They've most likely parsed/sanitized their user input so that you can't enter HTML via form inputs and most likely you would have to modify the JS to do what you're after...

Comment: @NickParsons I am entering this in an internal cms system where I only have access to enter data into a form and trying to read it from a rest service which again I could only read from. When I try to go back to edit the entered data, thats when I noticed the br tag has been modified to above.

Comment: Hmm, I see, have you maybe tried using the newline escape character? (`\n`)

Comment: @NickParsons \n has no effect. Comes out as plain text.

Comment: It sounds like the text you are entering is sanitized (as mentioned above,) in this internal application.  If the code that is displayed in your application is not being read by the html interpreter this is probably expected behavior and it is not something that you will just be able to change using a different method of input.  

The "CMS" application you are using most likely does not process your input in any way other than plain text.   Sorry.

Comment: @AndrewCarr But if it is a sanitised issue, it should work fine on W3School link above when I use ->  start &lt;br&gt; end  . It is not working there either thus I believe the entry is wrong like should there be a space or something. I don't know.. Grasping at straws here.

Comment: can you show how you are entering it in the w3 editor? like a screenshot?

Comment: @aprouja1 Added screenshot for reference.

Comment: w3 editor is good the code on the left block is already sanitize so it will never work as html  "& l t ;" is the code to print "<"